# What is difference between point and hitTest and how i can use hitTest?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I want add area of touch to my scrollView and i have the scrollView inside container view. the page of scrollView is less that container. I find a lot in internet how is the use in Swift 4.2 but nobody explain how use step by step the hitTest. What i hava do when i do the subclass of type UIView? How use this class after in the class that have the scroolView or the containerView?

Thanks.

This is the code.

```
import UIKit

struct scrollViewDataStruct {
    let title: String?
    let image: UIImage?
}

class PaymentsOptionsController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scrollView.delegate = self

    scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: "First", image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "amex")),scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: "Second", image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chase-debit-card_front")),scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: "Third", image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "amex"))]
    scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * (CGFloat(scrollViewData.count) + 1)
    var i: CGFloat = 0
    var j: CGFloat = 1
    let halfInterSpacing: CGFloat = 10.5
    let viewWidth : CGFloat = 305
    let viewOptions = PaymentMenuViewController(frame: CGRect(x: (halfInterSpacing * j) + viewWidth * i, y: 0, width :  viewWidth, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
    self.scrollView.addSubview(viewOptions)
    i += 1
    j += 2
    for data in scrollViewData{
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: (halfInterSpacing * j) + viewWidth * i, y: 0, width :  viewWidth, height: self.scrollView.frame.height))
        view.imageView.image = data.image
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)

        i += 1
        j += 2
    }
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
    }


    class CustomView: UIView {   
        let imageView : UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
        }()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
             fatalError("aaa")
        }
    }   
}


class PassThruScrollView: UIScrollView {

    var passThruViewRef: UIView?

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool    {

    return point.y > passThruViewRef?.frame.height ?? 0

    }

}
```

[Imagen from my stroyBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBRwi.png)

Comment: Hi, Rob i put my code and screenshoot of my storyboard. I don't know how extend the area of touch outside of scrollview with hitTest:Event.

Comment: Whit this "PassThruScrollView" class i can do that work but i thing that is not correct way. The way for i use this class is making a relation with this class in the object scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `hitTest` for the scroll view to recognize gestures outside of the scroll view, you need to [convert the coordinate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622498-convert) to the coordinate system of the current view:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    var referenceView: UIView?   // if you leave this `nil`, it will assume `superview`

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let view = referenceView ?? superview!

        let frame = convert(view.bounds, from: view)
        return frame.contains(point) ? self : nil
    }
}
```

FWIW, this works fine on the device but behaves strangely on the simulator, so use at your own risk.

But below I scrolled while doing gestures in the gray area, outside of the scroll view:

[image]